# Unexpected Identifier {...} after deploying MVC 6, AngularJS2, AspNetCore

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, iis-10

I got Syntax Error: Unexpected identifier (...) after publishing and adding MVC 6 .netcore website to IIS 10. everything is ok at developing environment and totally no error at all.

Is there anything that I missed out ?

here is my systejs.config.js file

```
(function (global) {
System.config({
    paths: {
        // paths serve as alias
        'npm:': 'js/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
        // our app is within the app folder
        app: 'app',

        // angular bundles
        '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
        '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
        '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
        '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
        '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
        '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

        // angular testing umd bundles
        '@angular/core/testing': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/common/testing': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/compiler/testing': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/http/testing': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/router/testing': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/forms/testing': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms-testing.umd.js',

        // other libraries
        'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
        app: {
            main: './boot.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        rxjs: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
});
```

})(this);

[image]

Here is my Project.json file

```
    {
  "title": "Focus Health Inc",
  "copyright": "copyrightByfrog",
  "description": "Focus Health ERP",
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "FHC.Data": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "FHC.Guard": "1.0.0-*",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1",
    "FHC.Generic": "1.0.0-*"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-*",
      "imports": "portable-net452+win81"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config",
      "Views"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please click on `(...)` and show us expanded error?

Comment: Hi @yurzui, I already updated the image. Thanks

Comment: usually, I found that the 'unexpected identifer' comes from an html file being returned and the first character of that file being `<` (for `<html...`).  This is probably a mapping issue between system.js and your .NET Core file structure in wwwroot.  a look at the network tab in chrome may be more helpful to find what path is returning the html file instead of a script file.

Comment: @DartfrogImi as yurzui said click on `(...)` it will show you more error details.

Comment: Please use the [tag:asp.net-core] tag for ASP.NET Core tags rather than asp.net-mvc-6.

Comment: @Sanket  I updated my image

Comment: @DartfrogImi verfiy your `boot.js` in your wwwroot folder structure.

Comment: yep that's the anwser